# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in QML array

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

**Alias.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 62

    property var arr : [1,2,3,4]
}
```

**Access.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: newq

    width: 100
    height: 62

    property var yy : [1]
    property var pp : [1]

    onPpChanged:
    {
        console.log("\npp: " +  pp.pop())
        console.log("\nyy: " + newq.yy.length + "\n")
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Alias
    {
        id: poi
    }

    Access
    {
        pp: poi.arr
    }
}
```

The error shows up on this line:
`console.log("\nyy: " + newq.yy.length + "\n")`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Check if this might be helpful: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/15244 and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-var.html

Comment: Perhaps you should use "variant" instead of var there? (see second code block here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-variant.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the `yy` property has not yet been initialised when `pp` is changed. You can see this by changing `Access.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: newq

    width: 100
    height: 62

    property var yy : [1]
    property var pp : [1]

    onYyChanged: console.log("yy changed: " + yy)

    onPpChanged:
    {
        console.log("pp changed: " + pp)
        console.log("\nyy: " + newq.yy.length + "\n")
    }
}
```

This outputs:

> qml: pp changed: 1,2,3,4
>
> file:///E:/Dev/Projects/qt/qml-test/Access.qml:17: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> qml: yy changed: 1

You can see that `yy` is eventually initialised, but not before `pp`. You should guard against this with an `if (newq.yy)` check, or refactor the code to avoid this situation, if possible.

The order of property assignments and bindings should not be relied upon, as QML is a declarative language.

Some related reading:

- [QML Applications](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmlapplications.html)
- [JavaScript Expressions in QML Documents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html)
- [Property Binding](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html)